# Angular Material div background image shrinks

Tags: css, angular-material

There are two images on my page, one is cover (.big-cover) and the other one is a card. When I add the card, cover image shrinks. I couldn't figure out why.

```js
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdDialog',
    function($scope, $mdDialog) {}
  ])
  .controller('DialogController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {});
```

```css
md-toolbar p {
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: auto;
}
md-toolbar {
  min-height: 30px;
}
.a133 {
  background: blue;
}
.a666 {
  background: red;
}
.big-cover {
  background: url(http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-277559.jpg) center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 45vh;
}
.change-cover {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.8.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">

<body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <md-toolbar layout="row">
    <p>NAVBAR</p>
  </md-toolbar>
  <div layout="column" class="big-cover">
    <div layout="column" layout-align="space-between start">
      <md-button class="md-raised md-primary change-cover">Change</md-button>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
    </div>
    <div layout="column" layout-align="space-between end">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div layout="column">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
      <div flex="80">
        <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
          <div flex="33" flex-sm="66" class="a133">[flex=33]</div>
          <div flex="66" flex-sm="66" class="a666">[flex=66]</div>
          <div flex="66">
            <md-card>
              <img ng-src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-277559.jpg" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
              <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                  <span class="md-headline">Card header</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
              </md-card-title>
            </md-card>
          </div>
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tmrd/9sehsndk/

Comment: I edited your code as snippet. It doesn't shrink for me neither here nor in fiddle. What browser are you using? One more thing: I haven't checked, but you should make sure the version of `angular-material` is compatible with the rest of angular dependencies and with angular itself. 0.8.3 is outdated.

Comment: Ya I was unable to duplicate as well in the fiddle using Chrome.

Comment: Testing with a newer version right now, update my question details soon.